# Why are there no icons/images in LibreOffice help browser?

Tags: libreoffice

Why in any page of the LibreOffice help (viewed with LibreOffice browser by pressing F1) can't I see any images/icons, but something which seems to be a default image with the name of the icon which should have been displayed (`vnd.sun.star.zip` most of the time)?